# Show $a_n=\Big(\frac{n^2+8n-1}{n^2-4n-5}\Big)^n$ converges to $e^{12}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show $$
> a_n=\left(\frac{n^2+8n-1}{n^2-4n-5}\right)^n
> $$
>   converges to $e^{12}$

My progress:
$$  
\frac{n^2+8n-1}{n^2-4n-5}=1+\frac{12n+4}{(n+1)(n-5)}
$$

Comment: $$ a_{n} =\left[ \left(1+\frac{12n+4}{(n+1)(n-5)}\right)^{\frac{(n+1)(n-5)}{12n+4}}\right]^{\frac{n(12n+4)}{(n+1)(n-5)}}$$

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: @SlavikEgorov If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by **asymptotic analysis**

$$a_n = (b_n) ^n$$

$$b_n =\frac{n^2+8n-1}{n^2-4n-5}=1+\frac{12n+4}{(n+1)(n-5)}\sim 1+\frac{12}{n}$$

$$a_n \sim \left(1+\frac{12}{n}\right)^n \to e^{12}$$

or with **little-o notation**:

$$b_n = 1+\frac{12}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{12}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n=e^{n\log {1+\frac{12}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}}=e^{n \left({\frac{12}{n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)}=e^{12+o(1)}\to e^{12}$$

Comment: What do you mean by ~?

Comment: @SlavikEgorov it means asymptotic equivalent i.e.$$ \frac{b_n}{1+\frac{12}{n}}\to 1$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis